# Print Entity Framework Model for documentation purposes?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Does anyone know how to print out an Entity Model schema? What I would like is a list of my tables (entities), along with the columns, their data type and sizes. I would to print this out to use for "reference". (I'm old school, I still prefer having stuff like this printed, versus "reading" it on a monitor.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to create an XSLT file that goes against your *.edmx file (which is just xml).  That way you can display the output however you want since the edmx contains all the meta-data you are seeking.